# my android app push notification is not working correctly on all type of android devices

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I am developing an android app and am trying to implement push notification.

My app works on Samsung 8 but it's not working on Samsung Note 5 running Android 7.0 or OPPO A73 with Android 7.1.1.

The problem is that the badge count is not showing on the app icon when a notification is received, only the sound plays but no badge count appears on the app icon.

When I test it with Samsung 5.0, if the app is in foreground the badge is showing but no sound and if the app is in the background the sound is working but no badge count.

Here is my source code:

```
  public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;

    public String titleOfNotification = "";
    public String messageOfNotification = "";


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Receiver service started: ");

        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        titleOfNotification = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        messageOfNotification = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        createNotificationChannel();
        handleNotification();

    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void handleNotification() {


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationsListActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "chan")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.kamarlogo)
                .setContentTitle(titleOfNotification)
                .setContentText(messageOfNotification)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setBadgeIconType(1)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

        notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

        Globals.badgeCount = Globals.badgeCount + 1;
        ShortcutBadger.applyCount(this,Globals.badgeCount);





    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "testchannel";
            String description = "test descripion";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("chan", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            channel.setShowBadge(true);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }





}
```